# Error Loading ModulesUnknown column 'control' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT id, title, module, position, content, showtitle

Tags: joomla

Getting this error when trying to login to our Joomla site.  Out of the blue Friday we started getting a 404 error on the frontside, and this error on the backend when logging into joomla admin:

---

> Error Loading ModulesUnknown column 'control' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT id, title, module, position, content, showtitle, control, params FROM jos_modules AS m LEFT JOIN jos_modules_menu AS mm ON mm.moduleid = m.id WHERE m.published = 1 AND m.access <= 2 AND m.client_id = 1 ORDER BY position, ordering

---

We added a new site to our server, and created a new database for the site, and in this process our main site quit working.  Has anyone ever seen this error or have any ideas?  When logging into Joomla backend, which we can do, it immediately displays the above error 3 times in a row, nothing more.  We are down now so any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the there is no column called "control" in either the jos_modules or jos_modules_menu tables. It would appear you may not have created a new database because it would seem that your databse has been altered.

I would recommend restoring from Thursday's back up then starting the new site from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The column Control was dropped from the #__modules table in version 1.7
So most likely you overwrote your database.

Go with the backup suggestion! (But backup what you have now).